# How to fix System Settings window lag

Tags: unity, performance, system-settings

I wanted to open *System Settings* window and I waited `~30s`. Then the window was opened.

My machine has an `Intel Core i7` processor and `16GB RAM`.

What produces a lag in opening *System Settings*? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Run in a terminal `gnome-control-center` and if any output is created before window appears, post it here.

Comment: @Cornelius No output, but still a ~5s lag...

Comment: It seems it doesn't care about system specs, because on my 2.66 GHz dual core with 2 GB RAM it opens up in 3-4 s on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits.

Comment: @Cornelius But why is it sooo slow?